# lock workstation using applet from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, dll, websocket, applet

I want to lock my workstation from a jsp. For that I have written an applet which uses JNA APIs and it is embeded in a JSP.

When I invoke the applet as a standalone applet it is working and my workstation is getting locked. But when I invoke it from JSP it is not working as expected. I can see that the applet is loaded and it is showing as "started in the "status bar", but it is not locking my workstation.

**applet code snippet**

```
    public void init(){

    User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    user32.LockWorkStation();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
     }
```

**jsp code snippet**

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" 
code="Applet.myApplet.class"   
width="200" height="100" align="top"
codebase="/workspace/applet">   
<jsp:fallback>    
<p>Unable to load applet</p>    
</jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong...also if there is any other approach to lock workstations, please advice...

Thanks,
Indranil

**Update on 2017** - Chrome has depricated NPAPI, it doesn't support dll anymore, IE also going in the same direction with Edge. only possible way to implement this solution is with websockets. If anyone interested, I can post the full solution as an answer.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or funny messages in your logs?

Comment: Any idea, why applet doesn't work?

Comment: Only option is to use VBScript...JAVA Script is not going to work. I have solved the problem using VBScript.